# Error while building AutoMapper source code

Tags: visual-studio-2017, automapper, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to build the [source code for AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) so I can better understand it, but I'm getting the following errors:

[image: Error while building AutoMapper]

I've tried Visual Studio 2017 since it was recommended [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#platform), but it's using the wrong version of C# and gets syntax errors.  And the above errors were generated in Visual Studio 2019.  I also tried running the [Build.ps1 PowerShell script](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/Build.ps1), but this failed as well.

The [Contribute.md](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#building) indicates that I should run psake.cmd to build the solution, but I don't see that file in the source.

Can someone provide tips on how to build AutoMapper source code?

Comment: You don't need to build it, you can step through the code with SourceLink. Other than that, it builds for me just fine in VS 2019.

Comment: SourceLink looks cool, I haven't seen that before.  Thanks for sharing.  I would still like to get the code compiling so I can run through the unit tests.  I wonder if I'm missing any components from my Visual Studio install.

Comment: Perhaps. Build.ps1 works too, so definitely smth on your end.